# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'csv'

Tags: python

i can't read csv file in my function!!

```
  def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
with (open(input_file_name,'r')) as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin)
        for row in reader:
        name=row[0]
        grades=list()
        for grade in row[1:]:
            grades.append(float(grade))
            with open(output_file_name,'w') as f:
             for item in grades:

              f.write("%s\n" % item)

f.close()
return f
```

and when calling my function:

```
 calculate_averages(input.csv ,output.csv)
```

i have this error:

```
 calculate_averages(input.csv ,output.csv)AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'csv'
```

but i had created input.csv file and output.csv file!!!
what am i doing wrong??

Comment: What do you intend by `input.csv` (and `output.csv`)?  Name of a file?.  The `csv` attribute of the `input` object?

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the filenames in quotes, like so:

```
calculate_averages('input.csv', 'output.csv')
```

Comment: when i do it i have thise error:  
 with (open(input_file_name,'r')) as fin:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.csv'   but i created this files!!!!

Comment: What directory does `input.csv` live in, and what directory are you in when you run your python script?